# export styles to ArcPad 10

Tags: arcmap, arcpad, arcgis-10.1

I cannot export or add styles to AXF files, to style the AXF file in mobile device.

Using the ArcPad Check out Tool from Python, I can save an AXF file without styles because I reference the feature classes from the geodatabase, but I would like to add symbology style to this AXF file.

I tried exporting Stylesheet file .APS, I've added it to an Applet (copy and past XML text) but it didn't work. When I use the tool "ArcPad Check out" from ArcMap it exports with style inside every layer definition, I would like to know also if there's a manner to set Document (mxd) as Context in arcpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that Layer files (.lyr), can store symbology and Data access information, and they could be referenced in the script by their path. I tested the checkout tool with the Layer file as input, and the output of the layers with symbols worked perfectly fine.